# JavaFX - ListProperty conditional binding

Tags: javafx, binding, listproperty

in my code i have a tableview bound to a ListProperty.
I am able to retrieve all the data correctly but i need to apply a condition to this data set based on a specific property of each object in it.
Is it possible?
This is the model:

```
public class Ticket {

private String number;
private String sys_id;
private String short_description;
private String description;
private String opened_by;
private String assigned_to;         // tabella esterna
private String assignment_group;    // tabella esterna
private int incident_state;         // 2: assigned - 3: wip - 4: hold
private String sys_created_on;
private Date sys_updated_on;
private int priority;               // 1: critical
private boolean isVisible;          // per nasconderlo nella tabella riassuntiva
private boolean isAlarmed;          // per silenziare le notifiche
```

In the controller i have bound the tableview to a ListProperty (returned by ticketService.ticketsProperty()):

```
serviceNowTicket_tableView.itemsProperty().bindBidirectional(ticketService.ticketsProperty());
```

I just need to filter this by the ticket "isVisible" property.
Maybe via BooleanBinding?

Comment: unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: If you want to filter, you might consider to wrap a filteredList around your base list. Hard to tell from your description, so please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: naming convention is ok in the whole project, this class is just an exception because it maps a JSON and i wanted to maintain the original keys

Comment: Are you replacing the`items`list or the`ObservableList`wrapped in the`ListProperty`anywhere?If not using a(bidirectional) binding is not necessary here.Usually you'd use a[`FilteredList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/collections/transformation/FilteredList.html)for this but this list is unmodifiable and assumes the predicate result doesn't change for an item without an update change being triggered for the`ObservableList`which doesn't happen unless you create the `ObservableList`a very specific way and would require you to store the`visible`property in a`BooleanProperty`.

Comment: The ObservableList is modified by a ScheduledService which takes a JSON and converts it into Object to put/remove from the list